# Read a string from a txt file and compare it with items in drop down list using webdriver/java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the scenario:

1) create a file with input string=Sep 2015
2) Collect the drop down list into an array
3) if array equals string come out of loop else downloads new month report and overwrites txt file with new month name.

I tried below code, but I'm unable to implement the txt comparision part and txt overwrite part, please help.

```
driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
          //maximizing the window
          driver.manage().window().maximize();

          List<WebElement> options;
          int i = 0;
          do
          {
              options = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
              if(options.get(i).getText().equals("Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)"))
              {

                  System.out.println("old month");
                  break;
              }
              else
              { if (options.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("All" )){

                  System.out.println("Download new month");

                  WebElement identifier = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
                Select select1 = new Select(identifier);

                  //select1.selectByVisibleText("Oct");

                 select1.selectByVisibleText("Oct 2015 (Unconventional wells)");


                  Wait(20000);
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();
                  Wait(70000);
                  //Click on File save button
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']")).click();
                  //wait time to load the options
                  Wait(20000);
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a")).click();
                  //fprofile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
                  //fprofile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
                  Wait(10000);
                  String str=options.get(2).getText();
                  System.out.println("str: " + str);

                 // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                  System.out.println("Oct month data downloaded in csv format");
                  //System.out.println("New month");
              }
              } } while (i++ < options.size());
    }
```

Comment: Do u want to check string(i.e., sep 12) is equals to drop down list string?? If both are equal then we have to proceed or what?

Comment: No, if Sep is previous month and if it matches don't download, if not matches then that is a new month so we have to download it. Then again get txt of new month and overwrite it to txt file (so that this again becomes old month). This is how it has to work :(

Comment: There v hav Jan-Dec in a same string, here we have two months in a same string. Then how can u comes to know which is old month??

Comment: If the previous month is not equal to the first item in the list that means it is the new entry in the drop down, so we need to download the report. If no new entry is updated in the drop down it should say no new month then no need to overwrite the file, if there is a new entry download the report and overwrites that month name into the file

Comment: for now we enter manually Sep 2015 as the old month , next time onwards it overwrites

Comment: can u please tell actually where u are facing problem? is your code getting  correct value from drop downlist or is there problem in comparing with file data or others???

Comment: Hi, sry for the delay. Will update my code.

Comment: public class stack8 {

 public static void main(String[] args)  {
   stack8 obj=new stack8();
   try {
    //obj.beforeMethod();
    //obj.beforeMethod();
    
   obj.oilGasTestng();
   obj.getTheOldMonthFromFile();
   obj.afterMethod();
  
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 }
 
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//private WebDriver driver;
private String fileName = "E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month";
private File file;


public void oilGasTestng() throws InterruptedException {
 
 //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: could you please move to chat, so that I can share you the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try like this:

//Global Variable:

```
private WebDriver driver;
private String fileName = "/home/saritha/Desktop/MySeleniumFile.txt";
private File file;
```

In Tesng method:

```
@Test
public void oilGasTestng() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
    WebElement mSelectElement = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("//select[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
    List<WebElement> optionsList = mSelectElement.findElements(By
            .tagName("option"));

    for (int i = 2; i < optionsList.size(); i++) {
        WebElement element = optionsList.get(i);
        String newMonth = element.getText();
        /*
         * First we have read the data from file, if the file is empty then
         * download the file and save the downloaded month(which is old
         * month when v done with the downloading).
         */
        String oldMonth = "";
        if (i > 2) {
            oldMonth = getTheOldMonthFromFile();
        }
        System.out.println("Old Month= " + oldMonth + " NewMonth= "
                + newMonth);
        if (newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
            // IF the string are same, nthng we need to do
        } else if (!newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
            /*
             * If the string are not same,then i.e., considered as new
             * Month, download the new month details
             */
            element.click();
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']"))
                    .click();
            System.out.println(newMonth
                    + " month data downloaded in csv format");
            saveIntoAFile(newMonth);
            /*
             * You can which is oldMonth which is new month, by unCommenting
             * below condition
             */
            // if (i == 4)
            break;
        }
    }
}


//Save data into a file
 private void saveIntoAFile(String oldMonth) {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    if (oldMonth != null) {
        file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            Writer writer = new FileWriter(file);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bw.write(oldMonth);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (bw != null) {
                    bw.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

//Get the oldMonth string from the file
private String getTheOldMonthFromFile() {
    if (file == null && !file.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    String oldMonth = "";
    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    java.io.FileReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new java.io.FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while ((oldMonth = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strBuffer.append(oldMonth);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return strBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98871/discussion-on-answer-by-saritha-g-read-a-string-from-a-txt-file-and-compare-it-w).

Comment: hi saritha garu, u thr?

Comment: deniki property file kavali anta andi, like file path ki

Comment: Hi saritha, happy new year :)

Comment: Hi usha..Thnq wish u d same..:))

Comment: the scenario which you have helped right, that is in hard code. how to use helper class and config.properties and to make my code appear so that is not hard coded?

Comment: hi saritha, there?

Comment: Yes..what is the prblm??